# unwrap and wrap a li element with a tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to wrap two list elements with an a tag. By default only one list again has the a tag. When that element is clicked I want to remove the a tag from the clicked element the add it the other listed element. Then when the second element will be clicked do the same thing. I used these follwoing two functiosn that work if they are in different html document but when I put them together. Only one works. Any help?

```
var pTags = $( "#ab" );
var pTags1 = $("#cd");

$( "#xx" ).click(function()
{
if ( pTags1.parent().is( "a" ) ) 
{
pTags1.unwrap();
pTags.wrap( "<a href='#' id='xv'></a>" );
}
});
$( "#xv" ).click(function()
{
if ( pTags.parent().is( "a" ) ) 
{
pTags.unwrap();
pTags1.wrap( "<a href='#' id='xx'></a>" );
}
});
</script>



<!doctype html>


<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>unwrap demo</title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"
    type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
<li id="ab">Hello</li>
<a href="#" id="xx"><li id="cd">cruel</li></a>
</body>

<script>

var pTags = $( "#ab" );
var pTags1 = $("#cd");

$( "#xx" ).click(function()
{
if ( pTags1.parent().is( "a" ) ) 
{
pTags1.unwrap();
pTags.wrap( "<a href='#' id='xv'></a>" );
}
});
$( "#xv" ).click(function()
{
if ( pTags.parent().is( "a" ) ) 
{
pTags.unwrap();
pTags1.wrap( "<a href='#' id='xx'></a>" );
}
});
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: your html is not valid as `li` must be a child of a `ul`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/fhs13rqe/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first off your html is invalid `li` should be a direct child of a `ul` or `ol`.

u need to use the `on` event handler becuase when the second element is wrapped the click event won't attach to it.

```
<span id="ab">Hello</span>
<a href="#" class="clickable" id="xx"><span id="cd">cruel</span></a>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(document).on('click', 'a.clickable', function () {
            var id = $(this).attr('id');
            $('span', this).unwrap();

            if (id == 'xx') {
                $('#ab').wrap("<a href='#' class='clickable' id='xv'></a>");
            }
            else if (id == 'xv')
                $('#cd').wrap("<a href='#' class='clickable' id='xx'></a>");

        });
    });
</script>
```

this is just a sample and there are better ways of doing it, if you be clear about what you want to do ?

Comment: Hi Arjun and Exlord, thanks for your solutions. I will try them and let you know.